# Is the charset parameter allowed on application/octet-stream MIME type

Tags: email, smtp, mime-types

I am working on a project where I need to send requests over email instead of http,
to prevent email servers or clients from messing with the body (especially urls) I have set the `Content-Type` header in my SMTP request to `application/octet-stream` instead of `text/plain`.
The content however is actually plain text so I also specified `;charset=UTF-8`.
Looking at [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.1.2) it seems that the `charset` parameter is only allowed for `text/*` types, however I also found many examples where `charset` was used with `application/*` types.

Now I wonder, is `application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8` a valid MIME type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `application/octet-stream` definition [(IANA-RFC)](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream) doesn't define a charset for this applicationtype and the definition for `application/json` [(IANA-RFC)](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json) a mimetype thats used more often includes a note:

```
No "charset" parameter is defined for this registration.
Adding one really has no effect on compliant recipients.
```

I would strongly recommend to assume that the statement not only applies in this special case, but also in other `application/*` which have no `charset` defined.

So I can't say if it is valid to pass parameters that aren't defined, but the RFC clearly implies that the `charset` parameter for `application/octet-stream` (and other `application/*` that do not define `charset`) has no effect.