# How to return an InputStreamResource so it can readable from postman?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, inputstream, response-entity

So I have a method

```
@GetMapping(
            value = "/download/{fileId}",
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE }
    )
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(@Valid @PathVariable(value = "fileId") String fileId) {
        InputStreamResource file = new InputStreamResource(service.download(fileId));

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileId+".doc");
        headers.add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .body(file);
    }
```

and when I hit the API from postman, it returns :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzSoT.png)

How can I make the output readable and downloadable from postman?

Comment: By the way, you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637127/is-the-charset-parameter-allowed-on-application-octet-stream-mime-type

Comment: And this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975718/how-to-download-excel-xls-file-from-api-in-postman